# Gulp coverage fails with "Error: Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`"

Tags: javascript, gulp, mocha.js, code-coverage

I'm trying to run unit tests & coverage on my code using Gulp.

I have the following dependencies on my `package.json`:

```
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-coverage": "^0.3.38",
    "gulp-mocha": "^7.0.2",
```

And I have the following gulpfile:

```
gulp = require('gulp');
mocha = require('gulp-mocha');
cover = require('gulp-coverage');

gulp.task('test', function () {
    return gulp.src('test/**/*.js', { read: false })
            .pipe(cover.instrument({
                pattern: ['src/**/*.js'],
                debugDirectory: 'debug'
            }))
            .pipe(mocha())
            .pipe(cover.gather())
            .pipe(cover.format())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('reports'))
});
```

Now, when I run `gulp test` the tests run but coverage doesn't:

```
C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-services (master) (cognitive-se
rvices@1.2.3)                                                                 
λ gulp test                                                                   
[21:03:19] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-services\gulpfile.
js                                                                            
[21:03:19] Starting 'test'...                                                 


  API Test                                                                    
    √ should throw an error if a body parameter is required for json and not p
resent                                                                        
    √ should throw an error if the boolean body parameter has a value other th
an true or false                                                              
    √ should throw an error if a body parameter is required and its value is n
ot in the list of options                                                     
    √ should throw an error if a parameter is required and not present        
    √ should throw an error if more than one parameter is required but not pre
sent                                                                          
    √ should throw an error if a parameter is required and its value is not in
 the list of options                                                          
    √ should accept a list of options for parameters                          
    √ should throw an error if the boolean parameter has a value other than tr
ue or false                                                                   
    √ should not throw an error if the endpoint is supported                  
    √ should throw an error if the endpoint is not supported                  
    √ should throw an error if a header is required but not present           
    √ should throw an error if more than one headers are required but not pres
ent                                                                           


  12 passing (9ms)                                                            

[21:03:22] 'test' errored after 3.51 s                                        
[21:03:22] Error: Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`                     
    at DestroyableTransform.normalize [as _transform] (C:\Users\mparn\Document
s\GitHub\node-cognitive-services\node_modules\vinyl-fs\lib\dest\prepare.js:16:
17)                                                                           
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\n
ode-cognitive-services\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:1
82:10)                                                                        
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\
node-cognitive-services\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:
170:83)                                                                       
    at doWrite (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-services\node_m
odules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)                        
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-services\
node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:395:5)                   
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\no
de-cognitive-services\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322
:11)                                                                          
    at Pumpify.Duplexify._write (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitiv
e-services\node_modules\duplexify\index.js:208:22)                            
    at doWrite (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-services\node_m
odules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:406:64)                        
    at writeOrBuffer (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-services\
node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:395:5)                   
    at Pumpify.Writable.write (C:\Users\mparn\Documents\GitHub\node-cognitive-
services\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:322:11)
```

Comment: Also posted here https://github.com/dylanb/gulp-coverage/issues/57